# Kdiff3 - Tool launch failure in TortoiseHg

Tags: tortoisehg, kdiff3, difftool, tortoisemerge

I am having issues with my TortoiseHg when it tries to launch Kdiff3.
It gives me an error "C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\lib\kdiff3.exe: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified". I couldn't find any solutions online.

I do have kdiff.exe in the path mentioned in the error and permissions are set properly.  Tried uninstalling and reinstalling it, but still getting the same error. Running Tortoise as an administrator, didn't help either.

I don't have any issues pulling, committing or pushing changes.  The issue is only related to the kdiff tool.

Has anyone encountered this issue and resolved it successfully?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem, is likely to be an **environment variable** with the wrong value: https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issues/4217/error-2-the-system-cannot-find-the-file

Variable `ComSpec` should have a valid path to `cmd.exe`.

Comment: ComSpec is set to the path of cmd.exe only.